# RQuantlib - FixedRate Bond with negative Rates

Tags: r, quantlib

Following up on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592547/using-rquantlib-fixedratebond-function-when-rates-can-be-negative), is there a way to price a Bond with negative rates?

I use R (3.5.3) and installed the current version of RQuantlib (0.4.10). When I try to price a Bond with negative rates I always get the same error as in the linked thread:

```
Error in FixedRateWithRebuiltCurve(bond, rates, schedule, calc, c(discountCurve$table$date),  : 
invalid value (-0.00505955) at index 0
```

Comment: it would help to have a reproducible example 
 in your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592547/using-rquantlib-fixedratebond-function-when-rates-can-be-negative